# Why the curve fitting line is disorganized?

Tags: r, curve-fitting, lines

[image: curve fitting]

Hello, I want to know why the fitted curve in the picture looks so bad and is not just one smooth line?

```
plot(df$Q,df$C)
cur=lm(C~I(1/Q),data=df)
lines(df$Q, predict(cur), col = "green")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Because the values were not ordered by the x-axis values.

Comment: To start, read here on how to make a sample data set: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Instead you should sort both the predicted and X values by the X values order. One way to do that is to pass an ordered set of values to the lm function. Then the predicted values will also reflect that ordering:

```
 plot( df$Q, dg$C )
 cur  <- lm(C~I(1/Q), data=df[order[df$Q), ] )
 lines(df$Q, predict(cur), col = "green")
```